# cmake install xxxTargets.cmake with a different name from the original target

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to create a xxxConfig.cmake file using the xxxTargets.cmake generated file with a custom target name different from the original target name.

Currently i'm doing this:
I install the desired target (let's call it 'originalName') with:

```
install(TARGETS originalName
        EXPORT destinationNameTargets
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${INSTALL_BIN_DIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}
        INCLUDES DESTINATION "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}"
)
export(TARGETS originalName
    FILE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/destinationNameTargets.cmake")
install(EXPORT destinationNameTargets 
    DESTINATION
       ${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}
    NAMESPACE MyNS::
)
```

And what i want is that the final target name (the one in the destinationNameTargets.cmake) has the 'destinationName' instead of the 'originalName', like this:

```
# Create imported target originalName
add_library(destinationName SHARED IMPORTED)
```

But what happens is that the target name will allways be equal to the original one...

Is it possible to change the target name of the generated target file? if is how can we achieve this?

Comment: As far as I know, you may only add a *prefix* to original target name (this is what `NAMESPACE` option does). You cannot change the target name completely.

Comment: yap i'm also using the prefix functionality too (NAMESPACE) but i wanted to rename the target... i also tried with add_library(... alias ...) and then use the alias and this failed!!! don't realy understand why...