# How to have separate names for a target, its filename, and its export name?

Tags: cmake, buildconfiguration

I have some target - say it's a library - in a `CMakeLists.txt` file of a repository I'm working on. I want to the following three to be separate:

1. The target name I use in `CMakeLists.txt`; say it needs to be `foo`.
2. The exported target name, which others will use after importing my installed repository: The prefix is `mypackage`, and I want the target name to be, say `bar`, so together it will be used as `mypackage::bar` by the importer.
3. The library file basename; I want it to be `libbaz`, not `libfoo` nor `libbar`.

How can I achieve this?

I *may* be able to achieve two of these three using the `ALIAS` modifier of the `add_library()` command, but I want all three.

Comment: By assigning property [OUTPUT_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html) you could have any of the library file. However, *original* and *exported* target names could differ only by **prefix** (NAMESPACE parameter for [install(EXPORT)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-exports)). Using `add_library(ALIAS)` you could **duplicate** original and/or exported targets with new names, but old names would still be accessible.

Comment: Another question about customizing **exported target name**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704087/cmake-install-xxxtargets-cmake-with-a-different-name-from-the-original-target.

Comment: And the question about changing name of the library **file**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038963/how-do-you-rename-a-library-filename-in-cmake.

Answer (score 2):

There are target properties that control this: `OUTPUT_NAME` and `EXPORT_NAME`. Here's how I would implement your scenario:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(mypackage)

add_library(foo ...)
add_library(mypackage::bar ALIAS foo)

set_target_properties(
  foo
  PROPERTIES
  OUTPUT_NAME "baz"
  EXPORT_NAME "bar"
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
set(mypackage_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/cmake/mypackage"
    CACHE STRING "Installation destination for CMake files")

install(TARGETS foo EXPORT mypackage-targets)
install(
  EXPORT mypackage-targets
  DESTINATION "${mypackage_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}"
  NAMESPACE mypackage::
)

# not shown: other install rules, components (incl. above), etc.
```

See the docs:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_NAME.html